# How to pass values from state in vuex post request

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am collecting data using get and set for my form. I want to post the states to the api.
How can I move the states or group them somehow so I can pass them as to action?

```
  state: {
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",

  },
  mutations: {
    setFirstName(state, value) {
      state.firstname = value
    },
    setLastName(state, value) {
      state.lastname = value
    },
```

So it looks like this:

```
sendInfo({commit}, object) {
axios.post('API_URL', object)
.then((response) => {
 ...
})

}
```

```
computed: {
            firstname: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.firstname
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit("setFirstName", value)
                }
            },
```

or am I approaching this wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to put these values inside a state object like:

```js
state: {
  user: {
    firstname: '',
    lastname: ''
  }
}
```

You can set the object in an action

```js
actions: {
  setData({ commit }, payload) {
    commit('SET_DATA', payload);
  }
},
mutations: {
  SET_DATA(state, payload) {
    state.user = payload;
  }
}
```

It also makes it concise when using `mapState`:

```js
computed: {
   ...mapState(['user'])
}
```

Comment: Do I need an action to set data? I've used get set to set a state for my multi-step form. I will edit my post and show the code for this.

Comment: No, commit is fine too.  You would just remove the action from my answer and use the mutation.  The rest would stay the same.  But your edit shows how you would do it if you want to change individual properties.  My answer was for your question about changing them as a group.

Comment: But the get/set is not only one, I have like 5 of them on different views.

Comment: So when I group them in state as payload: { }, in the mutation I change 
```state.firstname = value``` to ```state.payload.firstname = value```?

Comment: It becomes trickier when trying to use the individual values reactively in a form like your edit because you need an individual computed setter on each one.  Or a workaround like cloning the object

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/h9DN0DK.png Can you see the screenshot? Does the postInfo({commit}, payload) should have payload or SET_DATA ?

Comment: Same way as the action in my answer

Comment: What If I pass state as parameter, should this work?
```postInfo({state}) {
      axios.post('api_url', { 
        name: state.firstname
      })
    }```

Comment: Yes if the data is already set, but `state.user.firstname` if using my example.  You could also do this:  `postInfo({ state }, payload) { axios.post('api_url', { name: payload.firstname })}`